recyclerview-selection touch conflict with ItemTouchHelper move
I'm using recycler recyclerview-selection for selection and ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback for reorder the items. Like below:

I can drag and drop the icon on the right (green) part for reordering, also I can touch anywhere on the viewholder for selection.
The problem are:

When I drag the icon the item also be selected. (the checkbox is enable state)
When I touch the icon the item also be selected.

Is anyway to just touch the red rect for selecting and the icon for dragging?
I tried to both:
    holder.binding.reorder.setOnLongClickListener {
        touchHelper.startDrag(holder)
        true
    }
    holder.binding.reorder.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
        if (event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            touchHelper.startDrag(holder)
        }
        return@setOnTouchListener false
    }

onLongClick and Touch to distinguish the gestures, but still the same effect. Thanks in advance!

The problem arises because both onLongClick and onTouchListener for the reorder icon (green part) end up triggering selection along with the drag initiation.

Using customized SelectionTracker.SelectionPredicate solved my issue.
SelectionTracker.Builder(...
            ).withSelectionPredicate(object : SelectionTracker.SelectionPredicate<String>() {
})

